# Wrong data fetch from firestore collection (Flutter Android)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have entering the world of flutter since 2 months ago and currently im making my first app to show a list of diseases data on my homepage with an on pressed event to redirect to each disease detail page. I have successfully to show the diseases data on the list homepage but the detail page is showing incorrect disease data

[HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bub28.png)

[Detail Page of Septicemia shows Adenoviruses instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqYRx.png)

heres my firestore data structure
[Firestore Collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KawJ.png)
[Firestore Subcollections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J4Dl.png)

heres my code to retrieve the disease data on listview

```
    class FetchLibrary extends StatefulWidget {
  final _firestoreKategori = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('testing')
      .orderBy('namaPenyakit')
      .snapshots();
  FetchLibrary({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FetchLibraryState createState() => _FetchLibraryState();
}

class _FetchLibraryState extends State<FetchLibrary> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: widget._firestoreKategori,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, asc) {
            String listKategori = snapshot.data!.docs[asc]['namaPenyakit'];
            return CardItem(
              listKategori: listKategori,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String listKategori;
  CardItem({Key? key, required this.listKategori}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CardItemState createState() => _CardItemState();
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(widget.listKategori),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DiseasePage(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and heres my code for fetching the diseases detail data from firestore

```
   class FetchDisease extends StatefulWidget {
  FetchDisease({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FetchDiseaseState createState() => _FetchDiseaseState();
}

class _FetchDiseaseState extends State<FetchDisease> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> penyakit =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('deskripsi').snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: penyakit,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('error');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          final data = snapshot.requireData;
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Deskripsi\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiPenyakit']}",
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      "Gejala Umum\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiGejala']}",),),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      "Pencegahan\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiPencegahan']}",),),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      "Pengobatan\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiPengobatan']}",),),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me solve this problem, I cant find any solution to this problem on the internet or tutorials

Answer (score 0):

```
class _FetchLibraryState extends State<FetchLibrary> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: widget._firestoreKategori,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, asc) {
            String listKategori = snapshot.data!.docs[asc]['namaPenyakit'];
            return CardItem(
              listKategori: listKategori,
              docId: snapshot.data!.docs[asc].id;
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String listKategori;
  String docId;
  CardItem({Key? key, required this.listKategori}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CardItemState createState() => _CardItemState();
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(widget.listKategori),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DiseasePage(
              docId:this.docId
             ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To fetch Data of specific disease you have to give docId for that document As

```
 class FetchDisease extends StatefulWidget {
  FetchDisease({Key? key,this.docId}) : super(key: key);
  final String docId;

  @override
  _FetchDiseaseState createState() => _FetchDiseaseState();
}

class _FetchDiseaseState extends State<FetchDisease> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> penyakit =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('testing').doc(this.widget.docId).collection('deskripsi').snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: penyakit,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('error');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          final data = snapshot.requireData;
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Deskripsi\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiPenyakit']}",
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      "Gejala Umum\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiGejala']}",),),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      "Pencegahan\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiPencegahan']}",),),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      "Pengobatan\n${snapshot.data!.docs[0]['deskripsiPengobatan']}",),),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! but when i tried to implement the docId ive got a multiple error such as:
1) docId: snapshot.data!.docs[asc].id, //(The named parameter 'docId' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'docId'.) 

2) MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DiseasePage(docId: this.docId), // (1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.)
            ),
          );